# Representing complex numbers in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, complex-numbers

I'm new to python, sorry if this seems awfully rudimentary for some. I know complex numbers can be simply represented using j after an integer e.g.

`a = 2 + 5j`

However when I try something like the code below, python returns an error and doesn't recognise this as being complex?

`x = 5`

`a = 2 + xj`

Similarly this doesn't work:

`a = 2 + x*j`

How can I get around this problem. I'm trying to use this principle is some larger bit of code.

Comment: `a = 2 + x*1j` or use [cmath](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmath.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `j` is like the decimal point or the `e` in floating point exponent notation: It's part of the notation for the number literal itself, not some operator you can tack on like a minus sign.

If you want to multiply `x` by `1j`, you have to use the multiplication operator. That's `x * 1j`.

The `j` by itself is an identifier like `x` is. It's not number notation if it doesn't start with a dot or digit. But you could assign it a value, like `j = 1j`, and then `x * j` would make sense and work.

Similarly, `xj` is not implicit multiplication of `x` and `j`, but a separate identifier word spelled with two characters. You can use it as a variable name and assign it a separate value, just like the names `x`, `j` and `foo`.

Comment: Just add to @gilch notes: >>> cmath.sqrt(-1) # 1j

>>> y = cmath.sqrt(-1);
>>> x * y     # 5j

Answer (score 3):

Use the complex() constructor:

Code:

```
x = 5
a = complex(2, x)
print(a)
```

Output:

```
(2+5j)
```